# Saving java links?? Or something of the like?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Sorry for the horrid title but since I'm no programmer I really don't know how to phrase what it is I'm looking for...

Ok so I'll describe; I constantly need access to a certain website to look up information for my research (see below).  I thought I could just use a program like HTTrack but after the entire website was saved to my local machine, I was still unable to open the links that had the info I am looking for.  If I hover over the link, in the bottom left of the page does not show an "http://...." it shows a "javascript:view_NGO..." So there is something special about these links.  I am familiar with computers but I am not a programmer so I don't really know what I need to do in able to save that information.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the webpage I am working with: http://ngo.india.gov.in/state_ngolist_ngo.php?records=1&state_value=

There are roughly 50,000 "Links" (the "link" I need is the one under Name of VO/NGO) I would need to save to gather the required info.  Any suggestions???

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand your question, but it seems as though you could just mark the page as a "favorite" in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at what is displayed in the bottom left when you hover over a link, you will see something like this:

> javascript:view_ngo('A','B','C','D')

where A, B, C, and D are numbers.

When you click the link, the web page is actually submitting a form with these hidden values and landing you at http://ngo.india.gov.in/view_ngo_details_ngo.php. Therefore all links seem to go to the same page.

However, there is a trick to bookmark the page for a specific record. Use this address, substituting in the appropriate values of A, B, C, and D:

> http://ngo.india.gov.in/view_ngo_details_ngo.php?ngo_id=A&records_no=B&page_no=C&ngo_black=D

As far as saving ALL of them, I don't know what to tell you.

---

**EDIT:** It looks like the records_no (B) and page_no (C) portions are not actually used and you can leave them out. All you need is the ngo_id (A). ngo_black (D) changes whether or not a "Black Listed" link appears at the top so it may be relevant for certain records.